# Firebase emulator: add build steps to hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I'm trying to programmatically build my `index.html` file from a template, using a custom script/pre-deploy hook.

Is it possible to have the Firebase emulator run my predeploy script either (1) on start, or (2) on page refresh, so that I can see in the emulator what will happen on actual deploy?

My script works in actual deployment, but never fires with the emulator.

firebase.json (relevant part)

```js
"hosting": {
  "public": "public",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "predeploy": "node ./preDeploy.js",
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
},
```

preDeploy.js (oversimplified minimal example)

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const testString = 'hello';
fs.writeFileSync('./preDeployTest.txt', testString);
```

I would expect the test file to be generated (1), ideally every time I refresh my site while running the emulator, or (2) at least when I first start the emulator -- but the script only runs on actual deploy.

To be clear, I'd be using this script to generate the file that I want Firebase hosting to use as its `index.html`, but I want to be able to emulate the results.

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible with the default lifecycle [scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts) block:

```
"scripts": {
    "prepare": "node ./prepare.js"
}
```

There's also `preprepare` and a few other hooks; you may have to toy with it to find the correct one. The point is, that one isn't limited to Firebase specific hooks, but can use those defined by NodeJS.

Comment: Where in `firebase.json` does "scripts" go?  I'm not seeing it in the "hooks" docs.  Or, could you point me to the relevant docs?

Comment: Ah, or are you meaning just in `package.json`?

Comment: Also, `package.json` is only in the `/functions` folder, so how would this affect hosting?  I guess I'm not understanding how to implement your suggestion -- maybe you could provide a minimal example of how this would fit into a project file structure?

Comment: @ultraGentle Why aren't you unable to click the link to the documentation?? And why you ask for another example, when I already provided one? Sorry, but  won't spoon you.

Comment: The docs you linked are Node JS docs, not Firebase docs.  It's not clear to me how to implement what you're describing in relation to the Firebase emulator, which does not seem to have a place for arbitrary scripts.  Hence my question.